# web/desktop application for sharing websites for showcase purposes

Tags: open-source, desktop-client

here, in my company we need to share stuff with people. I mean when we saw some website that is cool to watch and learn stuff from it we share it across our network (LAN Chat via XMPP).

but as we grow up we get loose in all of this stuff.

what we want is:

Share websites

Show screenshot of websites as thumbnail

Category

Tag

Comments

Rate

Free (we can host it by ourselves too)

Have desktop application (windows)

so, what do you suggest?

Comment: Would a Wiki be the right solution for you?

Comment: @Sonamor we tried wiki but we have some problems with it. its ugly. no commenting. no rating . no auto thumbnail generator.

Comment: I don't know any existing tool that would do all of these. You could try a WordPress installation with a post for every website. You can add tags, you can do comments, and it can create a thumbnail, maybe with a plugin, you can add a rating as well.